# Full screen in virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, macbook-pro, fullscreen

I have a Macbok Pro 13" and I'm using virtualbox to run ubuntu 12.04. My problem is I can't resize ubuntu for occupy the 13" of my screen when I use full-screen mode. Ubuntu only allows me to use two screen size options, 1024x768 or 800x600. The 800x600 option is too small, and cuts the screen in a smaller size with black edges.With the 1024x768 option, i only have black edges on the left and on the right. Is there any option for extending the image at the whole screen?

Comment: Did you install Guest Additions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When logged into the virtual machine:

1. In VirtualBox UI, use menu Devices | Insert Guest Additions CD image...
2. They will ask to download the .iso CD image.
3. Select Yes, and once the download completes it it will ask you if you want to install the same.
4. Go through the steps on the installer (mostly click `Yes` or `Next`)
5. Restart the Virtual machine, if needed.

Enjoy!

Comment: I have done the same for CentOS in the Mac OS host. I can Install Guest additions but this doesn't change anything.   Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

Installing Guest additions works perfectly fine. Just in case if someone still facing the screen size issue as i was facing, you can follow the below steps :

`sudo apt-get update`   // just to get all system dependencies

`sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso` // to get guest additions

and the final one
`sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms`.

Please let me know if anyone still faces the issue.

Comment: I did the same, but does not work. these steps worked for me for windows and Linux host OS, but someone I can't get it working on OS X host machine. I am using 13' map

Answer (score 4):

There's one extra step I needed in order to get Guest Additions to work on MacOS Mojave. With the VM shut down, go to VM Settings -> Display -> Screen. **Enable 3D acceleration** and max out the RAM (128MB works for me but virtualbox.org recommends 256MB). You can then restart the VM with your newly full-screened situation.

This solution also fixed my problem of having a discrepancy between where my mouse was on the screen and where it was actively pointing. This made it hard to press buttons, etc.

SOURCE: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=91086

Comment: Worked with a MBP 13" running macOS Big Sur, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu 20.04 in a MacBookPro 13"

1. In **VirtualBox** > **Settings** > **Display Video Memory** = 64MB
   [VM Settings panel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6VCf.jpg)
2. In Ubuntu20.04 [Virtual Machine]

   **Settings** > **Displays** > **Resolution** = 2560x1600

   **Settings** > **Displays** > **Scale** = 200%

   [image: Ubuntu20.04 settings panel screenshot]

Not FULL SCREEN, but it works for me

Answer (score -1):

you need to install the guest additions in order to access the fullscreen mode

Comment: Care to explain how this can be installed?